# Generate map coordinates to be on streets

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I have a PHP program that generates a certain number of random coordinates on a map in a specified radius. I want check which points are positioned in a user-accessible area such as a street; not on buildings.

I was thinking of generating a query for directions, getting the highlighted map and making sure the points are positioned on the lines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I created a random point within the radius and then asked the Google Directions API to get directions from the center point to the new random point. It returns the end point which is accessible by walking.

```
//create random point from start within 300m radius
$lat0 = someLatitudeCoordinates
$lon0 = someLongitudeCoordinates
$r = 300/111300; // = 300 meters
$y0 = $lat0;
$x0 = $lon0;
$u = myRandom();
$v = myRandom();
$w = $r * sqrt($u);
$t = 2 * pi() * $v;
$x = $w * cos($t);
$y1 = $w * sin($t);
$x1 = $x / cos($y0);

$newY = $y0 + $y1; //new random lat point within 300m
$newX = $x0 + $x1; //new random lon point within 300m
//now we created a point. first, fix it by making sure its accessable
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin={$y0},{$x0}&destination={$newY},{$newX}&mode=walking";
$dir = file_get_contents($url);
$directions = json_decode($dir, true);

//newLat and NewLon are points accessable by walking, and not on a building or in a water source
if (count($directions["routes"])!=0) { //if we got a result
  $newLat = $directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["end_location"]["lat"];
  $newLon = $directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["end_location"]["lng"];
}
```